# Who sells broken up sets of sefarim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, books-generally

I lost one volume of my Mikraos Gedolos.  I cannot find a sefarim store that is willing to sell me just the one volume, and cannot find it on Amazon.  Is there a website or store that is willing to break up sets of sefarim to sell individual volumes?

Comment: do you live in EY?

Comment: Dittos. Still looking for a part two to my chassam soffer al hatorah.

Comment: @Nafkamina Unfortunately, not yet.

Comment: @user6591 I've been doing shnayim mikra at shul for the past few weeks, because I am missing devarim (and I do Targum Yonasan, which I don't have in any other sefer)

Comment: @YEZ well if you know anyone in yerushalayim across from mannys is a store which sells either pagum sefarim or sefarim which are out of set, hey have PILES of out of set mikraos gedolos lying there for very cheap- i dont remmeber the name though, its next to a tailor and fafafel store

Comment: @Nafkamina Is manny's the schwarma place?  I thought across from there is an empty plaza and a bus stop.

Comment: @Yez not going pry you for your location but your best bet is to find which local seforim store sells pieces and hope to get lucky. Best bet is in Boro park which has Pinters. Next best is upstate in woodridge. Theres a famous sfarim store that sells odds and ends at times. Cant remember the name.

Comment: no manny is a book store. check on google maps: Khavakuk St 5 its the store with a white door on the right of the tailor

Comment: http://www.feldheim.com/nach-mikraos-gedolos.html

Comment: Many shuls that have geniza will allow you to buy the individual volumes. They often get broken sets since some of the volumes are in decent condition. It depends on where you are. For example the Agudah in Baltimore has a room with many sefarim that came in via geniza but are still usable and can be bought. Of course, that would not help unless you can get there (perhaps by teleporting in) (:-)

Comment: @Nafkamina Manny's is Habakuk 2. https://www.librarything.com/venue/77351/Mannys

Comment: If you live in NYC, Beigeleisen (sp?) and the other store two doors down from them (forget the name) both sell used sefarim out-of-set

Comment: @Bachrach44 i understand, i wrote the address of the store which is down the block and across from manny's, i was just using it as a reference point being that manny's is a famous bookstore

Comment: @Yitzchak that could be an answer!

Comment: @Nafkamina oh now I remember manny's - has the long hallway entranceway

Comment: Which publication is your Mikraos Gedolos? Maybe I have a broken set... Its in Tel Aviv but if you know someone who have a flight to NY.... (Its the end of summer, many jewish come back frome israel to NY...)

Comment: @YEZ, I moved it

Comment: @YEZ Just wondering what the source of doing it with yonasan is. Do you also do onkelos or Rashi?

Comment: @user3949142 No I do just Yonasan.  It is no worse than doing just Rashi.  The only loss is in not doing Onkelos I lose the נאמרה בסיני part.  But Targum Yonasan has its own aspects that it is identified for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of options that have worked for me in the past:

1. [Ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xmikraot%20gedolot&_nkw=mikraot%20gedolot&_sacat=0) is your friend. I'm currently seeing a few dozen single volumes for sale there, although obviously the selection will fluctuate.
2. I've had good luck getting single volumes at used book sales and used book stores. Stores that focus exclusively on new books won't be much help here. What metro area are you in? If you're in the DC/Baltimore area I can point you to a few used book sellers that might be able to help. In NYC try Mizrahi Book Store (3114 Quentin Rd, Brooklyn NY 11234). I've even found random seforim turn up in the foreign language sections of regular run-of-the-mill used bookstores in Jewish areas.
3. Beyond that you can try abebooks.com (used books galore) and amazon. With both of those two you may have to spend some time with alternate spellings, translations, and transliterations in order to find what you need, but the more common stuff (like mikraot gedolot) can be found on those two sites. If what you want has an ISBN that's definitely the way to go.

Comment: I got my missing chumash at Mizrahi Book Store - checkmark for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in NYC, Beigeleisen (sp?) on 16th avenue in Brooklyn, and the other store two doors down from them (forget the name) both sell used sefarim out-of-set.

Answer (score 1):

Online you can contact http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/ which sells individual volumes.

In Lakewood there is a Sefarim store in the basement of the Capital Hotel that sells used Sefarim and sells many individual volumes.

Answer (score 0):

Some places have thrift stores / Gemach's. Occasionally, you find "loose" sefarim, there

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find individual volumes of the The Pentateuch and Rashi’s Commentary - A Linear Translation into English on Amazon.com.

Answer (score 0):

Start out by using a [used book metasearch engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=used+book+metasearch) to look for what you want. I know a couple of (secular) used booksellers and I hear that http://used.addall.com/ is good.

If that doesn't work, set up email alerts with various websites. Start out by setting up an AbeBooks "want" and an Ebay saved search with email notifications.

AbeBooks supports Boolean searches, wildcard searc*, fuzzy~ searches, and "proximity searches"~2. See [their instructions](http://www.abebooks.com/docs/boolean/). Wildcard and fuzzy searches are especially useful when searching for transliterated titles.

Ebay advanced search supports Boolean logic. See [their instructions](http://pages.ebay.com/help/search/advanced-search.html#using).

As Bachrach44 pointed out, you may have to spend some time with alternate spellings, translations, and transliterations. You should also try pasting the Hebrew title of the book you want into the search box: some sellers add Hebrew to their listing title or keywords.

Which volume of your Mikraos Gedolos is lost? How did you lose it? And may I ask (approximately) where you live?